# Generate core dump in ant script under linux

Tags: ant, coredump

I'm trying to generate a core dump of application from ant script.
At the moment I am able to generate core dump from ant script by encapsulating possibly crashing program with bash script. I would like to generate core dump without this extra bash script.

**My minimal working example:**

My environment: xubuntu 20.04 lts, ant 1.10.12.
Core pattern is set using command:
`sudo sysctl -w kernel.core_pattern=/path/to/home/crash/core_%e.%p_%t`
Target folder has rwx permissions.

My test application:

```
int main(int a, char * b[])
{
    throw "crash";
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with:
`g++ -ggdb crash.cpp -o crash`

My test.xml ant script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE project>
<project name="Crash" default="crash-bash" basedir=".">
    <description>Crash test</description>
    <property environment="env"/>    
    <target name="crash-bash">
        <exec executable="bash">
            <arg value="-c"/>
            <arg value="./test.sh"/>
        </exec>
    </target>
</project>
```

My test.sh bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
ulimit -S -c unlimited
ulimit -H -c unlimited
ulimit -S
ulimit -H
cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
./crash
```

Executed as:
`ant -f test.xml crash-bash`

Produces core dump in expected folder:

```
Buildfile: /path/to/home/crash/test.xml

crash-bash:
     [exec] unlimited
     [exec] terminate called after throwing an instance of 'char const*'
     [exec] ./test.sh: line 7:  2567 Aborted                 (core dumped) ./crash
     [exec] unlimited
     [exec] /path/to/home/crash/core_%e.%p_%t
     [exec] Result: 134

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

Unfortunately when I tried to execute something similar - without bash script as intermediary - it doesn't generate core dump.

**My not working example:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE project>
<project name="Crash" default="crash" basedir=".">
    <description>Crash test</description>
    <property environment="env"/>
    <target name="crash">
        <sequential>
            <exec executable="bash" failonerror="true">
                <arg value="-c"/>
                <arg value="ulimit"/>
                <arg value="-S"/>
                <arg value="-c"/>
                <arg value="unlimited"/>
            </exec>
            <exec executable="bash" failonerror="true">
                <arg value="-c"/>
                <arg value="ulimit"/>
                <arg value="-H"/>
                <arg value="-c"/>
                <arg value="unlimited"/>
            </exec>
            <exec executable="cat" failonerror="true">
                <arg value="/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern"/>
            </exec>
            <exec executable="./crash"/>
        </sequential>
    </target>    
</project>
```

Executed by:
`ant -f test.xml crash`
Results in:

```
Buildfile: /path/to/home/crash/test.xml

crash:
     [exec] unlimited
     [exec] unlimited
     [exec] /path/to/home/crash/core_%e.%p_%t
     [exec] terminate called after throwing an instance of 'char const*'
     [exec] Result: 134

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

Application crashes as expected, but core dump is not generated.

What I tried so far:

- specifying different paths to kernel.core_pattern
- comparing environment variables
- tried to search core dumps in other locations(if by any chance it would get generated in different folder)
- using `vmlauncher` parameter to `exec` task with true and false values
- compiling application also with `-dH` switch

Any suggestions what could be the problem?